# Tensorflow hang at compute_gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having an issue where my Tensorflow execution is getting stuck at `compute_gradients`. I am initializing my model and then setting up the loss function like so. Notice that at this point I haven't began training so the issue is not my data.:

```
# The model for training
given_model = GivenModel(images_input=images_t)

print("Done setting up the model")

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    with tf.variable_scope('prediction_loss'):
        logits = given_model.prediction

        softmax_loss_per_sample = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels))


        total_training_loss = softmax_loss_per_sample

        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        gradients, variables = zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(total_training_loss))
        gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, gradient_clip_threshold)
        optimize = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))


    with tf.control_dependencies([optimize]):
        train_op = tf.constant(0)
```

This code just hangs and doesn't do anything. When I ctrl+c out of it (no matter how long of running), it is always stuck at the `compute_gradients`.

Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening? I am not doing this inside a loop and my model is not that big. It also seems to be using the CPU to do this (no memory allocated on GPU yet), and I can't force it to use the GPU despite the `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):` option.

Thanks

Here is what prints when I do ctrl+c:

```
gradients, variables = zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(total_training_loss))
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 35$
, in compute_gradients
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 48$
, in gradients
    in_grads = grad_fn(op, *out_grads)
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_grad.py", line 269, in _$
eluGrad
    return gen_nn_ops._relu_grad(grad, op.outputs[0])
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 2212, $
n _relu_grad
    features=features, name=name)
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", l$
ne 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2395, i$
 create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1268, i$
 __init__
    self._control_flow_context.AddOp(self)
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line $
039, in AddOp
    self._AddOpInternal(op)
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line $
062, in _AddOpInternal
    real_x = self.AddValue(x)
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line $
998, in AddValue
    real_val = grad_ctxt.grad_state.GetRealValue(val)
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line $
001, in GetRealValue
    history_value = cur_grad_state.AddForwardAccumulator(cur_value)
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 8
92, in AddForwardAccumulator
    self.forward_index.op._add_control_input(push.op)
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1434, in
 _add_control_input
    self._add_control_inputs([op])
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1422, in
 _add_control_inputs
    self._recompute_node_def()
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1442, in
 _recompute_node_def
    self._control_inputs])
  File ".local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1317, in
 name
    return self._node_def.name
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at this point you did not began the training, maybe it is related to the graph construction. Are you sure that the GivenModel is correct?
Because I adapted this autoencoder [example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/autoencoder.py) with your definition of the optimizer as below and I did not found any problems when executing this code:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# Training Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
num_steps = 10
batch_size = 8

# Network Parameters
num_hidden_1 = 256 # 1st layer num features

num_hidden_2 = 128 # 2nd layer num features (the latent dim)
num_input = 784 # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)

# tf Graph input (only pictures)
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_input])

weights = {
    'encoder_h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input, num_hidden_1])),
    'encoder_h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_1, num_hidden_2])),
    'decoder_h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_2, num_hidden_1])),
    'decoder_h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_1, num_input])),
}
biases = {
    'encoder_b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_1])),
    'encoder_b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_2])),
    'decoder_b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_1])),
    'decoder_b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input])),
}

# Building the encoder
def encoder(x):
    # Encoder Hidden layer with sigmoid activation #1
    layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['encoder_h1']),
                                   biases['encoder_b1']))
    # Encoder Hidden layer with sigmoid activation #2
    layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['encoder_h2']),
                                   biases['encoder_b2']))
    return layer_2


# Building the decoder
def decoder(x):
    # Decoder Hidden layer with sigmoid activation #1
    layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['decoder_h1']),
                                   biases['decoder_b1']))
    # Decoder Hidden layer with sigmoid activation #2
    layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['decoder_h2']),
                                   biases['decoder_b2']))
    return layer_2

# Construct model
encoder_op = encoder(X)
decoder_op = decoder(encoder_op)

# Prediction
y_pred = decoder_op
# Targets (Labels) are the input data.
y_true = X

# Define loss and optimizer, minimize the squared error
### your code with a reconstruction loss
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    with tf.variable_scope('prediction_loss'):

        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(y_true - y_pred, 2))

        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        gradients, variables = zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(loss))
        gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, 5.0)
        optimize = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))

    with tf.control_dependencies([optimize]):
        train_op = tf.constant(0)
### end of your code

# Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Start Training
# Start a new TF session
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)

    # Training
    for i in range(1, num_steps+1):
        # Prepare Data
        # Get the next batch of MNIST data (only images are needed, not labels)
        batch_x, _ = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

        # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
        _, l = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={X: batch_x})
        # Display logs per step
        print('Step %i: Minibatch Loss: %f' % (i, l))
```

So, I think that maybe the problem is with the rest of the model, but to be sure we need further details of the model.

Now, about whether the placement of the model is in cpu or gpu. If you did not define anything being on cpu, the gpu device will be automatically selected for you. So, in theory the model will be allocated on gpu automatically. But, again, maybe the graph construction has problems and it did not reach the point when the model is actually allocated in the gpu memory.

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't getting to the point where it could put itself on GPU. When I made the model smaller, it worked. So I guess if the model is above a certain size, compute_gradients hangs on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that the model was too big. Making it smaller fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem with three cause:

1. model to large, so decrease batch size
2. there is var with no gradient:

   ```
    clone_gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(total_clone_loss)
    for grad_and_vars in zip(*clone_grads):
        tf.logging.info("clone_grads"+str(grad_and_vars))
   ```

   It prints:

   INFO:tensorflow:after clone_grads((, ),)
   INFO:tensorflow:after clone_grads((None, ),)